How do I scrape the specific data I want?
I am taking my first crack at data scraping and am having trouble getting the specific data I want. Ultimately, I want to identify all players that were born and/or played high school baseball in Colorado and save their name and place of birth in a dictionary. I'm able to identify the tag(s) the data is contained within, but I haven't been able to successfully retrieve the data.
I have studied scraping extensively but haven't been able to make much progress. It seems to me that I need to use soup.find_all('tag', attrs={}) to parse the data I need, but I have had difficulty determining how to identify the data I want with 'attrs'. If there is a relevant post for this topic already, I'm happy to review that as well. I was unable to find a post that was helpful, likely due to a lack of technical knowledge on my part.
If the B-Ref homepage is https://www.baseball-reference.com/.
Thank you
#Python program to scrape website

import requests
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

URL = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/paytoja01.shtml'
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

#print(soup.prettify())

a_tag = soup.find_all('a')

print(a_tag)
#Colorado_Born_and_HS = {}
#Colorado_Born = {}
#Colorado_HS = {}

I have tried a variety of approaches including soup.find, .find_all, .find_all_next, .next_siblings, etc. I did not include all of these in the sample of my code because it was messy and I imagine this question has a relatively simple answer.

Your URL leads to a page that shows images of 12 players (out of 23,370). Are you hoping to analyse just those initial 12 or do you want to examine the entire dataset? Also, there's a lot of JavaScript going on on that site. You may get unexpected results if you just use BeautifulSoup. You should consider installing and using selenium

@SIGHUP The player photos are just a site feature. I ultimately want to build a program that iterates (I think that's the right word) through all 23,370 player pages and adds players that were born and went to high school in CO in one dictionary, players who were born in CO but didn't go to high school there in another dictionary and players who went to high school in CO but weren't born here in another dictionary. Also, I'll check out Selenium. Thank you

Here I found the date for your example:
#Python program to scrape website

import requests
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/paytoja01.shtml'
r = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

# Using soup
birthday = soup.find('span', id="necro-birth")
print(birthday.text.strip())

# Using plaintext
txt = str(r.content)
born_dirty = txt.split("was born in")[1].split("</a>")[0]
born = born_dirty.split("<")[0] + born_dirty.split(">")[1]
born = born.strip()

print(born)

output:
November 22, 1972
Zanesville, OH

Reading the page the URL leads to, I noticed that the date of birth is in a span with an id. This is ideal since we can find that simply.
That said, I don't usually use BS4 for scraping, I simply take the text of the page and split it on points of interest until I get what I want. That is the "plaintext example". Note that I ctrl+F the Zanesville on the page the URL leads to and decided I want to use the second occurrence so I went after that. If the FAQ is not auto-generated, this might not be universal.
You can throw in some asserts for sanity checks, like replacing:
born_dirty = txt.split("was born in")[1].split("</a>")[0]

with
t1 = txt.split("was born in")
assert(len(t1) == 3)
born_dirty = t1[1].split("</a>")[0]


I've gone through a few versions of the code you provided above and am encountering an IndexError and 403 error. The data seems to be accessible, so I'm guessing the 403 error is indicative of the code I'm using looking in the wrong spot for "was born in". I've used ChatGPT and GoogleColab AI to understand the cause of the error, but haven't been able to figure it out. I have started using selenium and that definitely helped. Thank you

GoogleColab was definitely the problem. I've switched to Virtual Code Studio and the code you provided works perfectly. Thanks for your help.

the site is hardly using semantics, so i understand why you had a hard time. with poorly structured html like here, the preferred solution is to use XPATH. but i like css selectors
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import re
re_city = 'in (.+?), '

URL = 'https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/paytoja01.shtml'
r = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

bio_paragraphs = soup.select('#meta > div:nth-child(2) p')

city_state = bio_paragraphs[3].select_one('span:nth-child(3)')
city = re.search(re_city, city_state.text).group(1)
state = city_state.a.text
print(f"{city=}, {state=}")

high_school = bio_paragraphs[5].a.text
print(f"{high_school=}")

output
city='Zanesville', state='OH'
high_school='Zanesville HS (Zanesville, OH)'


I originally encountered an IndexError, so I made the necessary adjustments. Now I'm getting the following error: "Error fetching page: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.baseball-reference.com/players/p/paytoja01.shtml" . . . So, it looks like the data isn't available to be scraped to me. But, that is different than what I thought when using code from the other users who responded. I think using Google Colab might be part of the issue. Thank you

you didn't talk about google collab in your question. that's not "part" of the issue, it's the issue. i think all three solutions are working with the information you provided first

I did not realize that using Colab was relevant. I’ll do some research on the differences between using a terminal, other code editors, etc. Thanks

@I've switched to Virtual Code Studio and your code works. Thanks

selenium is a better option for this as the site utilises JavaScript to format/render its content. BeautifulSoup is better suited to static HTML.
Here's an example of how you could use selenium (which you'll need to install if you don't already have it) to get the names and birth states of the players whose images appear on the main page.
You should be able to modify this to acquire the statistics you're really interested in.
You could also adapt this to use multithreading for improved performance.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

url = "https://www.baseball-reference.com/"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")

def text(e: WebElement) -> str:
    if r := e.text:
        return r
    return e.get_attribute("textContent") or "n/a"

def wait(driver: WebDriver|WebElement) -> WebDriverWait:
    return WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

def get_player_info(url: str) -> tuple[str, ...]:
    with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        div = wait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "meta")))
        a = wait(div).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p span a[href]")))
        name = wait(div).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1 span")))
        return text(name), text(a[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        for a in wait(driver).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.images a[href]"))):
            if purl := a.get_attribute("href"):
                print(get_player_info(purl))

Output:
('Willie Randolph', 'SC')
('Eddie Guardado', 'CA')
('Ken Caminiti', 'CA')
('Rube Curry', 'MO')
('Paul Quantrill', 'Canada')
('Andy Cooper', 'TX')
('Jerry Nops', 'OH')
('Randy Wolf', 'CA')
('Don Mattingly', 'IN')
('Tony Lazzeri', 'CA')
('James Paxton', 'Canada')
('Hughie Critz', 'MS')


I've gone through a few versions of the code you provided above and am encountering a 404 error. Similar to the situation with the code Brambor provided, the data seems to be accessible, so I'm guessing the 404 error here is because the code I'm using is looking in the wrong spot for the data requested. I've used ChatGPT and GoogleColab AI to understand the cause of the error and some of the suggestions seem as though they may work. One issue may be that I'm using Google Colab. That seems to recur in some of the AI explanations. Thank you

@BrandonSmith I do not understand why, if you copy this answer exactly, you would get an HTTP 404 error. I have tested this multiple times without any such issues

no need for selenium on the reference.com sites. It's all in the source html

@SIGHUP on other comments they say 403. which makes more sense

With the code from other responses, I received a 403 error. With this code, it's a 404 error.

@sighup I've switched to Virtual Code Studio and it solved the issues. Thanks
